# React does not render, tried everything

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am a noobie and trying to do my full stack development course with FCC. Currently I am busy with React and my code does not render on the localhost. I have tried EVERYTHING, deleted NPM, Node, NodeJS, reinstalled all of it, reset my machine to an earlier backup I made before installing all these technologies but still NOTHING!! I am about to format my Linux and move back to Windows against my will. Can someone please please please help me and tell me what to do. The worst part is.... it's such simple code, but I am unable to make it work.

My HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Testing</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you serve your app ?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. I am using VS Code, not sure if that's what you are asking and then I started NPM so that I can see the changes on localhost:3000. Sorry if I am not giving the right info, I am a total idiot with this :D

Comment: Because I do not have much information about your case, you had created your react app like the docs said https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html 
And then with `npm start` in your folder your project does not start ?

Comment: yes that's basically right. I am doing the React tutorial video on youtube while going through the course of FCC.

Comment: And what error is appearing to you in the terminal?

Comment: There is no error and no output on the page

Comment: Does the style.css file exist? Have you tried inspecting the page using your browsers DOM inspection tool? Is the HTML body there? The root div?

Comment: No the style.css is empty

Comment: What about my other questions - have you inspected the page? Is it a white page? A white page isn’t necessarily empty, so first step would be to inspect that and see what’s there

Comment: True LOL, as said I am a newbie. When I inspect the page I can see it is the HTML code of the index.html file, so from my very limited understanding it seems that the HTML is not parching the info from the index.js file.

Comment: You could easily test to see if the js file is being read - before the line with ReactDOM.render, put console.log(‘Hello World’), save it, run npm start and reload the page. Then see if it gets logged to the browsers console

Comment: I have formatted my hard drive, reinstalled Ubuntu and finally got it fixed. Thank you so very much for all the help, it is much appreciated.